# Error The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel

Acabo de empezar con Laravel y me da este error con mi pagina de login para acceder a la parte de administración.

Dejo por aqui las clases afectadas y el log de rutas que devuelve la consola de comandos.

Formulario Inicio de sesión:

```
 <form class="mt-8" action="{{ route('admin.post.iniciar-sesion') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
            <div class="mt-4">
                <label for="email" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Correo electrónico</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" type="email" required placeholder="Correo electrónico" class="appearance rounded relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900  focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                <div class="flex justify-between">
                    <label for="contraseña" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Contraseña</label>
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.get.he-olvidado-mi-contraseña') }}"
                        class="font-medium text-xs text-brand-600 hover:text-brand-500 focus:outline-none focus:underline transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Contraseña olvidada?
                    </a>
                </div>
                <input id="contraseña" name="contraseña" value="{{ old('contraseña') }}" type="password" required placeholder="******" class="appearance-none rounded relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
            </div>
        </div>

            <button type="submit"class="group relative w-full mt-6 flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-brand-600 hover:bg-brand-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-brand-700 focus:shadow-outline-brand active:bg-brand-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                Iniciar sesión
            </button>


    </form>
```

Login controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


public function iniciarSesion(Request $request)
{
    $credenciales = array(
        'email' => 'admin@rp.es',
        'password' => 'realpolitik'
    );
    if (Auth::attempt($credenciales)) {
        // Authentication passed...;
        return redirect()->route('core.get.dashboard');
    }
    //La autenticación no ha funcionado
    return back()->with('error', 'Eypa!');
}

public function cerrarSesion()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->intended('inicio');
}
//
```

}

Rutas

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('inicio');
})->name('inicio');

Route::get('/quienes-somos', function () {
    return view('quienes-somos');})->name('quienes-somos');

Route::get('/iniciar-sesion', function() {
    return view('auth.inicio-de-sesion');
})->name('admin.get.iniciar-sesion');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'administracion'], function () {
    Route::post('/iniciar-sesion',[LoginController::class, 'iniciarSesion'])->name('admin.post.iniciar-sesion');
    Route::post('/cerrar-sesion', [LoginController::class, 'cerrarSesion'])->name('admin.post.cerrar-sesion');

    //Recuperar contraseña
    Route::get('/recuperar-contraseña/{id}/{token}', [UsuarioController::class, 'recuperarContraseña'])->name('admin.get.recuperar-contraseña');

    //Parte privada de la aplicación
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::view('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('core.get.dashboard');
        Route::view('/editores', 'core.editores')->name('core.get.editores');
        Route::view('/articulos', 'core.articulos')->name('core.get.articulos');
        Route::view('/articulos/añadir', 'core.añadir-articulo')->name('core.get.añadir-articulo');
        Route::view('/equipo', 'core.equipo')->name('core.get.equipo');
        Route::view('/equipo/añadir', 'core.añadir-equipo')->name('core.get.añadir-equipo');

        Route::view('/suscriptores', 'core.suscriptores')->name('core.get.suscriptores');


    });
});
```

Route List

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\rp2>php artisan route:list

+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                              | Name                                | Action                                                     | Middleware |
+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                                                | inicio                              | Closure                                                    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin                                            | admin                               | Closure                                                    | web        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | administracion/articulos                         | core.get.articulos                  | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                          | web        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | administracion/articulos/añadir                  | core.get.añadir-articulo            | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                          | web        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth       |
|        | POST     | administracion/cerrar-sesion                     | admin.post.cerrar-sesion            | App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@cerrarSesion          | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | administracion/dashboard                         | core.get.dashboard                  | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                          | web        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | administracion/editores                          | core.get.editores                   | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                          | web        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | administracion/equipo                            | core.get.equipo                     | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                          | web        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | administracion/equipo/añadir                     | core.get.añadir-equipo              | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                          | web        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth       |
|        | POST     | administracion/iniciar-sesion                    | admin.post.iniciar-sesion           | App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@iniciarSesion         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | administracion/recuperar-contraseña/{id}/{token} | admin.get.recuperar-contraseña      | App\Http\Controllers\UsuarioController@recuperarContraseña | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | administracion/suscriptores                      | core.get.suscriptores               | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                          | web        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth       |
|        | PATCH    | api/v1/articulo                                  |                                     | App\Http\Controllers\ArticuloController@index              | api        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/v1/articulo                                  |                                     | App\Http\Controllers\ArticuloController@index              | api        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | POST     | api/v1/articulo/crear                            |                                     | App\Http\Controllers\ArticuloController@crearArticulo      | api        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | DELETE   | api/v1/articulo/{id}                             |                                     | App\Http\Controllers\ArticuloController@index              | api        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/v1/miembros                                  |                                     | App\Http\Controllers\MiembroController@obtenerMiembros     | api        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | POST     | api/v1/miembros/crear                            |                                     | App\Http\Controllers\MiembroController@crearMiembro        | api        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | PATCH    | api/v1/miembros/editar/{id}                      |                                     | App\Http\Controllers\MiembroController@editarMiembro       | api        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | DELETE   | api/v1/miembros/eliminar/{id}                    |                                     | App\Http\Controllers\MiembroController@eliminarMiembro     | api        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/v1/miembros/{id}                             |                                     | App\Http\Controllers\MiembroController@obtenerMiembro      | api        |
|        |          |                                                  |                                     |                                                            | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD | he-olvidado-mi-contraseña                        | admin.get.he-olvidado-mi-contraseña | Closure                                                    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | iniciar-sesion                                   | admin.get.iniciar-sesion            | Closure                                                    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | quienes-somos                                    | quienes-somos                       | Closure                                                    | web        |
```

He probado todo lo que marca como solución stackoverflow, tanto n ingles como en español.
He probado a poner el método "put" en todo, cambiarlo por resources, me daba error este último.
No entiendo mucho laravel pero tiene pinta que las rutas están bien enlazadas, no entiendo porque aparece así.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error indica que estás enviando un verbo HTTP diferente al esperado, que es `POST`.

Luego de ver el método definido en el formulario y la declaración del verbo en la ruta, llegamos a la conclusión de que el problema se trata de caché.

Para eliminar el caché ejecuta el siguiente comando dentro de tu proyecto.

```
php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por responder tan pronto, he ejecutado el comando que me has comentado, y a la hora de volver a hacer login, ha tardado un poco mas de la cuenta pero el error persiste, según mi consola de comandos la limpieza se ha ejecutado correctamente.

Comment: Buenas de nuevo, al cambiar la ruta de "/dashboard" a POST en vez de view ya no me sale el error pero me aparece el error 419 Page Expired. ¿Es un error por cambiar esto último o tengo mal configurado mi administrador?

Comment: El error 419 generalmente se debe a la ausencia del token CSRF, eso da para otra pregunta ya que no hay contexto del problema, pero asegúrate de estar pasando dicho token en los respectivos formularios y a las rutas que generalmente son de tipo POST. También puedes desactivar el requisito de dicho token para una ruta en particular, en ````App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php```` , agregando tu ruta al array de ````$except````. PD: No se recomienda deshabilitarlo, pero te lo comento como opción.

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Nada, he echo pruebas y tampoco quiero que nos desviemos del problema, sigue saliendo el error de que la ruta no admite post, cuando el formulario login lanza un post y redirecciona al dashboard de administración, ¿este ultimo debe contener el error no?

Comment: Buenas, ya tengo la solución, resulta que en mi formulario estaba enlazando mal, haciendo pruebas cambie el action, ahora si funciona correctamente.